The Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$
Consider the four-dimensional representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$, given in terms of the following matrices
\begin{align}
J_1&=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
 0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad J_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & i \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad J_3=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
 0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
K_1&=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
 i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad K_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \quad K_3=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & i \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{align}
The matrices $J_i$, $i=1,2,3$ describe rotations, whereas $K_i$ are the boosts: they satisfy the following algebra
\begin{align}
[J_i,J_j]=i\, \epsilon_{ijk}J_k\,, \qquad [J_i,K_j]=i\,\epsilon_{ijk}K_k\,, \qquad [K_i,K_j]=-i\,\epsilon_{ijk}K_k\,,
\end{align}
with $\epsilon_{ijk}$ the Levi-Civita symbol.
I want to compute the weights of this representation, so I need to identify the Cartan subalgebra (the largest abelian subalgebra) and to find a suitable basis in which the corresponding generators are diagonal. 
Since $[J_1,K_1]=0$, I should expect to be able to diagonalise $J_1$ and $K_1$ simultaneously: however, take the matrix obtained from putting the eigenvectors of $J_1$ in columns
\begin{align}
P=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{i}{2} & -\frac{i}{2} & 0 & -1 \\
 \frac{i}{2} & -\frac{i}{2} & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,.
\end{align}
This indeed diagonalises $J_1$, but fails to do so for $K_1$:
\begin{align}
P^{-1}L_1 P=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right), \qquad P^{-1}K_1 P=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,.
\end{align}
Why is this the case and how do I overcome this problem?

You should be careful. $L_1$ has degenerate eigenvalues with eigenspaces that are two-dimensional. As the two matrices commute, you can find a basis where both are diagonal. For this, you should find eigenvectors of $K_1$ in the eigenspaces of $L_1$.

Why is the fact that $L_1$ has degenerate eigenvalues a problem?
By doing what you suggested, I was able to find a transformation that diagonalises both, but why does this work?

The commutativity just tells you that there both are simultaneously diagonalizable, however, if you have degenerate eigenvalues the eigenbasis is nonunique and the commutativity gives you no information about which basis is a common eigenbasis. (An extreme example is to look at the $0$ matrix and $A$ arbitrary which obv. commute)

Keep going. Diagonalize $P^{-1} K_1 P$, which has no effect on the former matrix.
